# Access Denied Error on Menus

Tags: 2013

Using the URL, users are able to authenticate and access our root site but the Nav Bar menu and side menu do not display. They just display "Error". However if a user access the site using the server name as the address instead of the URL the menus display. What could the permission problem be?

Here is the start of the error from the ULS log:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_AllProperties()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheProfile.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)

Answer (score 0):

Is your website URL added in Alternate access mapping?

To manage alternate access mapping:

1. On the SharePoint Central Administration website, click **System
   Settings**.
2. On the **System Settings** page, in the **Farm Management** section, click **Configure alternate access mappings**.

For more information, you can check below link:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc263208.aspx

Comment: Yes, alternate access mappings are set up. Also, there are some pages where I can see the menu. For example, if I go to the main page for the Finance or IT departments I can see the left menu but if I go to the HR department I get the access denied error on the left menu.